# SendKey not work for a Numeric on Chrome (Java)

Tags: google-chrome, java, selenium, salesforce

I'm in windows 10 64bit with a Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 and the latest Chrome Driver 75. I have a sendKey issue using Selenium on Java.
I have changed my computer recently and I have a regression on SendKey method for numeric value for some fields (type : decimal) in a salesforce application.

```
lstOfElements.get(0).sendKeys("120000");
```

For these fields, the SendKey send nothing.
I have use a workaround with Javascript :

```
WebElement t1 =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'input')]")).get(0);
t1.click();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='120000';", t1);
```

I can send the value but it's not recognize as a correct value (for sure the value put manually workq)

So I have used another workaround using

```
t1.sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD1);
```

And it works. 
But I target to manage my datset by external file and I would like to avoid the translation between the number and the NumPad command.

So, I have test same initial commande (SendKey("120000");) on FireFox using Gecko WebDriver, and it's working well.
Some other developper person with other configuration (Chrome 32bit on Windows 10 64 bit and same Driver) have the SendKey working well on Chrome also.
I have also change my conf to align it, but same issue.

Is someone know how come this sendkey issue, please explain me? May be there are an compatibility issue on chrome, because, when I have tested a robot keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1) it doesn't work since keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1); works.

Thanks for your help.
Hope I was clear.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `.clear();` before the sendkeys?

Comment: Yes I have tried it still not working.

Comment: TO avoid any driver issue , i have now create a maven project and use a github source in order to avoid chromedriver.exe. But I still have the same issue. I'm pretty sure their are something on my chrome browser. But I don't know what.